# Cgroup cpu subsystem，for a multi-thread process, is the value of cpu.cfs_quota_us / cpu.cfs_period_us related to the number of available cores?

Tags: cpu-usage, cgroups

I've been learning about the cpu subsystem in cgroup to limit the cpu usage of processes.

---

I understand that the maximum `CPU usage` available to a process is  `cpu.cfs_quota_us` / `cpu.cfs_period_us`

for example, if i set

`cpu.cfs_quota_us` = 1000000

`cpu.cfs_period_us` = 500000

The maximum CPU usage of this process is 200%.

---

**My question is**, for a multithreaded process (with more than 2 threads), does this 200% mean that the process can use up to 2 cores? Or does it mean that these threads perform at most 100% /cores * 200% of the time on all CPUs?